# Android; Dynamic Preference List with CheckBox and Detail Page

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I need to create config menu for our Android Java app, I'm struggling with the preferences construct the Android SDK has to offer, though.

This is how the result should look like (taken from our iOS app);

[image]

So basically a (dynamic) list with Checkboxes on the left and a detail page that will be displayed once the list item (NOT the checkbox!) has been clicked.

This is what I've got thus far;

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="items">

    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="pref_internal"
        android:title="List Items">
    </PreferenceScreen>

</PreferenceCategory>
```

The list items (which is basically a CheckBoxPreference) will get added dynamically like this;

```
PreferenceScreen internalTarget = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference("pref_internal");

 for(int i = 0; i<items.size();i++) {
        CheckBoxPreference box = new CheckBoxPreference(getActivity());
        box.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

                return true;
            }
        });
        box.setTitle(title);
        box.setKey(key);
        internalTarget.addPreference(box);
    }
```

So the question is, how do I change this to have list items that are selectable and lead to a detail screen, and have a selectable checkbox as well?
Are there any predefined preferences for this? If not, is there a way to create my own preferences, and how would the detail page switch work with those?